# Does my solution to the Smallest Difference algorithm problem have optimal space time complexity (O(nLog(n) + mLog(m)))?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting, data-structures

**Question**:
[image]

**Here is my solution:**

```
function smallestDifference(arrayOne, arrayTwo) {

    const combinedArray = [...arrayOne, ...arrayTwo];
    
    combinedArray.sort((a, b) => a - b);
    
    let smallestDifference = Infinity;
    let arrayOneInt = null;
    let arrayTwoInt = null;
    
    for (let i = 0; i < combinedArray.length - 1; i++) {
        if (Math.abs(combinedArray[i] - combinedArray[i+1]) < smallestDifference) {
            if (arrayOne.includes(combinedArray[i]) && arrayTwo.includes(combinedArray[i+1])) {
                smallestDifference = Math.abs(combinedArray[i] - combinedArray[i+1]);
                arrayOneInt = combinedArray[i];
                arrayTwoInt = combinedArray[i+1];
            } else if (arrayOne.includes(combinedArray[i+1]) && arrayTwo.includes(combinedArray[i])) {
                smallestDifference = Math.abs(combinedArray[i] - combinedArray[i+1]);
                arrayOneInt = combinedArray[i+1];
                arrayTwoInt = combinedArray[i];
            }
        }
    }
    
    return [arrayOneInt, arrayTwoInt];
}
```

**Here is the given optimal solution**

```
function smallestDifference(arrayOne, arrayTwo) {
  arrayOne.sort((a, b) => a - b);
    arrayTwo.sort((a, b) => a - b);
    let idxOne = 0;
    let idxTwo = 0;
    let smallest = Infinity;
    let current = Infinity;
    let smallestPair = [];
    while (idxOne < arrayOne.length && idxTwo < arrayTwo.length) {
        let firstNum = arrayOne[idxOne];
        let secondNum = arrayTwo[idxTwo];
        if (firstNum < secondNum) {
            current = secondNum - firstNum;
            idxOne++;
        } else if (secondNum < firstNum) {
            current = firstNum - secondNum;
            idxTwo++;
        } else {
            return [firstNum, secondNum]
        }
        if (smallest > current) {
            smallest = current;
            smallestPair = [firstNum, secondNum];
        }
    }
    return smallestPair;
}
```

For the above given optimal solution, it says the time complexity is O(nLog(n) + mLog(m)) and space complexity is O(1). Does my solution above it also match this time complexity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have loop over `combinedArray` which has lenght N + M. Within this loop you have `arrayOne.includes` and `arrayTwo.includes` with O(N) and O(M) time complexities.

So you have at least *O((N + M) ^ 2)* which is bigger than *O(n*Log(m) + m*Log(n))*

Comment: Thank you! I was unclear whether the includes was O(N) or not